# python pandas dataframe with more header confusion

Tags: python, pandas

**EDIT: as @J Richard Snape pointed out - "Multiline header" is called "hierarchical index" in Pandas, which is solved in different question**

I have two dataframes (there are corresponding indexes in each dataframe)

```
rep.head()

               zinc_ID
    Cluster No  
    3        ZINC08221075
    5        ZINC06920422
    7        ZINC06920381
    10       ZINC00968327
    4        ZINC08218951

ranked.head()
```

in case it is not obvious ranked dataframe  has two 'headers' the uppermost is 
`cons_all_rank` spanning over 4 cells (like merged cell in excel). It is a result of calling `groupby()` and `agg.([np.mean, np.std, np.median, len])`.

```
           cons_all_rank                       
                    mean         std median len
Cluster No                                     
1              94.689655  106.622198   37.0  29
2              79.638889  101.176268   55.5  36
3             175.826087  133.990384  144.0  23
```

I performed

```
out = ranked.join(rep)
out[:3]
```

and received

```
    (cons_all_rank, mean)   (cons_all_rank, std)    (cons_all_rank, median)     (cons_all_rank, len)    zinc_ID
Cluster No                  
1   94.689655   106.622198  37.0    29  ZINC08034993
2   79.638889   101.176268  55.5    36  ZINC32840901
3   175.826087  133.990384  144.0   23  ZINC08221075
```

Next I wanted to sort the `out` dataframe by performing

```
out.sort(columns='(cons_all_rank, median)')
```

but I keep getting

> KeyError: '(cons_all_rank, median)'

so I tried `out.sort(columns='zinc_ID')` and it worked flawlessly.
I also tried

```
out.sort('cons_all_rank, median')
out.sort('median')
```

but neither is working.
Is there a problem with the multiline header in `ranked` dataframe? If so, how can I get rid of it? `ranked.drop('cons_all_rank', axis=0, inplace=True)` did not work.

Comment: Is this what you want? stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/python-pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns

Comment: exactly! I didn't know what to look for. Now I know that "Multiline header" = "hierarchical index". Will you post an answer so others can easily see or shall I edit?

Comment: It's probably best to edit the question to highlight that what you were calling a "multiline header" is known in pandas as a "hierarchical index" and then mark it as a duplicate.  It's not in the spirit of Stack overflow to add an answer here, as the other one is exactly what you want, comprehensive and accurate as far as I can see.  Glad I could help you :)

Comment: @JRichardSnape You should flag it as a duplicate too.

Comment: @camdenl Yes, of course, just giving OP time to see comment / learn ropes round here

Comment: @JRichardSnape Cool, just wasn't clear from your comment.